# How to group chat with up to 1000 people?

Tags: skype, chat, whatsapp, telegram-messenger

We are a newly formed housing society with around 400 houses and up to 800 members. We want to set up a group chat among us via any app which is cross platform (Windows, Android, iOS).

We have tried:

- WhatsApp but it has a limit of 100.
- Telegram increases the limit up to 200 and
- Skype 300.

But none of these are sufficient.

Is there any way to increase the limit of any of these applications for up to 1000 people to chat together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If still relevant, you can go back to Telegram, it supports up to [100,000 members in a group](https://telegram.org/tour/groups#supergroups) (a supergroup, to be precise), and has apps for most platforms.

It also have nice admin and moderation tools to help you manage such enormous groups.

Answer (score 1):

IRC (Internet Relay Chat). IRC apps are available in every platform.

Comment: Please explain your answer. Is this available for phones/tablets? How to set it up? Any links?

Comment: You could probably use a client for the phone or tablet, or set up a webui. While irc dosen't log by default, having a bot for transcripts is fairly common.  Having that many people talk *simultaniously* though would be tricky